# Conditions for reciting על מקרא מגילה and שהחיינו on non-Esther megillot

Tags: blessing, shehecheyanu, 5-megilloth

Many today have the practice (usually following the Gra — see [Maaseh Rav 175](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91#%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%94)) of blessing על מקרא מגילה when reading Shir HaShirim, Ruth, Eicha, and Ḳohelet from a kosher scroll on Pesaḥ, Shavuot, Tish'a b'Av, and Sukkot, respectively, and additionally שהחיינו on all but Eicha.

Does anyone discuss any minimal conditions for reciting these *brachot*? For example: does it need to be attached to shacharit/musaf, mincha, or maariv?; does it need a *minyan*?; if it's read on the "wrong" day, does it get a *bracha*?; and perhaps other conditions. Is the answer different for the two different *brachot*?

Comment: The end of that Maaseh Rav has a story that is relevant

Comment: I believe there is an Igrot Moshe that is relevant (iirc story about not having a megilla on shabbat and wanting to read on last day of yom tov. probably if you search IM for "shir hashirim" it'll come up)

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks. The Maaseh Rav story is relevant, but it seems to have been on the same day (which is why I didn't ask about that setup explicitly). The Igrot Moshe reference is OḤ 4:99(2). He says that the particular day isn't important, but unfortunately doesn't address the other questions.

Answer (score 5):

The earliest source to make a *beracha* on reading the 5 *megillos* is Meseches Sofrim ([14:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%93)):

> ברות ובשיר השירים בקהלת באיכה ובמגלת אסתר צריך לברך, ולומר על
> מקרא מגילה, ואף על פי שכתובה בכתובים. והקורא בכתובים צריך לומר ברוך
> אתה י"י אלהינו מלך העולם אשר קדשנו במצותיו וציונו לקרוא בכתבי הקודש.

This is codified in Machzor Vitri ([Shavuos 312](https://www.sefaria.org/Machzor_Vitry%2C_Order_of_Shavuot.312.1?vhe=Machzor_Vitry,_Berlin,_1893-97&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) and Maharil (Seder Tefillos Pesach).

However, the Beis Yosef ([OC 559](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%98#fn_(%D7%91)_back)) quotes this opinion, but rules that the general custom is not to make a *beracha* (and so rules the Rema).

> כתבו הגה"מ יש במס"ס דאמגילת רות וקינות ושיר השירים מברך אקב"ו על מקרא
> מגילה וכן נהג הר"ם אכן יש לאומרה בנחת ובלחש עכ"ל והעולם לא נהגו לברך
> כלל על שום מגילה חוץ ממגילת אסתר

The Magen Avraham ([490](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A6_%D7%98#%D7%98_%D7%9E%D7%90)) discusses the origins of the various customs:

> כצ"ל דלא כמ"ש בדפוס קרקאקא השניי' וז"ל רמ"א בתשו' סי' ל"ה מהרי"ל
> ואבודרהם והג"מ פ"ה מהל' ט"ב כתבו לברך וכ"כ בד"מ לכן דקדקתי וכתבתי והעם
> נהגו כו' ולא כתבתי סתם וכן נוהגין כמ"ש בשאר מקומות וכן נ"ל מכמ' טעמים
> **דדוקא איכה שהחזן קורא להשמיע לצבור מברך** וכו' וכ"מ דעת המנהגים ועי"ל
> **דדוק' כשהם כתובים כתקנה בקלפים בגלילה מברכין אבל בחומשין שלנו פשיטא**
> **שאין לברך וכו'** עכ"ל אבל הלבוש וב"ח ומנהגים ומט"מ כתבו לברך על כלם חוץ
> מקהלת וכן עיקר כמנהג קדמונינו

Magen Avraham quotes two reasons from the Rema (Responsa 35) why not to bless: A blessing is only made when it is read *b'tzibbur* (specifically when one person is reading to the entire congregation), and only when reading from a kosher *megilla* (but not when reading from a Chumash). Nevertheless, the Magen Avraham rules that one should make a *beracha*.

The implication of the Magen Avraham is that he rules to bless even without fulfilling the two qualifications of the Rema. The Vilna Gaon explicitly rules so in *Biur HaGr"a*.

However, Maaseh Rav ([175](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91#%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%94)) brings the custom of the Vilna Gaon to specifically use real Megillah and to have a public *kriya*.

> בשבת חה"מ פסח וסוכות ובשבועות יום ב' אחר יוצרות קודם אין כמוך קורין
> המגלה בניגון וטעמי' **ממגלה הנכתבת בגליון כס"ת עם עמודים** ו**א' קורא
> וכולם שומעין ו**הקורא מברך שתי ברכות על מקרא מגלה ושהחינו.

Another important difference between the Magen Avraham and the Gr"a: the Magen Avraham rules is that although one should make a blessing on all *megillos*, Koheles is an exception. (See Machatzis Hashekel who explains why Koheles is different based on Shabbos 30b). The Vilna Gaon ([Maaseh Rav 175](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91#%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%94) and Biur HaGra) rules to bless even by Koheles.

**Is the Beracha only recited when attached Shacharis?**

Maaseh Rav brings a story when Megillas Rus was not read during Shacharis, and the Vilna Gaon ruled to read the Megilla during Mincha, with the blessings. Evidently, although the *minhag* was during Shacharis (see Rema 490), it can be fulfilled during Mincha too.

R' Moshe Shternbuch ([Teshuvos Vehanhagos 2:351](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20026&st=&pgnum=301)) ruled for his congregation in a time of need to recite the Megilla with the blessings before Shacharis in a different location.

**Is there a beracha on the 'wrong day'?**

This may depend on the classification of the blessing. Some understand that this beracha is on the *minhag*/*takanah* - accordingly, the beracha would presumably be only when the *minhag* is fulfilled. See Igros Moshe (OḤ 4:99(2), cited by @DoubleAA and @Magicker73 in comments), who posits that the *minhag* can be fulfilled over any day of Yom Tov.

However, the Emek Beracha (Birchos Hatorah 3) and the Brisker Rav (Chiddushei HaGriz, Hilchos Berachos) explain this *bracha* is not a *birchas hamitzvos* but a *beracha al hatorah*, a blessing which is made on any public reading of the Megillah. Accordingly, one could argue that the blessing would not be limited to the fulfillment of the *minhag*.

(Presumably, this does not apply to *Shehechiyanu*, which would only be because of the *minhag* as a *mitzva habah mizman lizman*.)

Comment: Thanks. The Maaseh Rav doesn't necessarily mean that he *requires* a public reading and a kosher megillah for a bracha — it could just come to exclude another popular minhag for everyone to read the megillah to themselves from a printed text with a bracha. (Haven't yet looked at the sources for your later sections.)

Comment: I would suggest you expand the details of R' Shternbuch's teshuva, because that gives a full approach to my questions for "al mikra megilla" (only chiyuv on tsibbur, need 10 to listen to the sha"ts to make a bracha, time of day is unimportant bedieved).